# Asymptotic running time in hash table

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

Since we know that if the hash function distributes the entries uniformly then the hash tables have O(1) query time.

What will be the asymptotic running time of:

(a) Adding n entries with consecutive keys in a separate-chaining hash table (the time to insert all, not each of them)

(b) Searching for a key that is not in the table.

My understanding is that inserting a key into a hash table is O(1) so for inserting such n entries will be O(n). For part b the search a key not present in table is considered as worst case so the asymptotic running time for searching will be O(n) as it would need to search all n values in the table.

Comment: What do *you* think they are, and why?

Comment: From my understanding inserting a key into a hash table is O(1) so for inserting such n entries will be O(n). For part b the search a key not present in table is considered as worst case so the asymptotic running time for searching will be O(n) as it would need to search all n values in the table. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about a) - it's O(n) where n is the number of new keys to be inserted, as each is O(1) with respect to the pre-existing number of keys.

For b) - you're wrong - it's O(1).  Searching for a key that is not in the table only has to exhaustively search the bucket to which the key hashes, and that bucket's expected length is roughly given by the load factor: the ratio of keys to buckets.  Most hash tables are designed to keep the load factor within a specific range, resizing the hash table as more keys are added.

For example, the C++ Standard specifies a default `max_load_factor` of 1.0, so if you insert say a 129th element into a table with 128 buckets, it will resize the whole thing to have perhaps 256 buckets (MS Visual C++ uses power-of-two bucket counts for fast bitwise masking of hash values to buckets, GCC uses prime numbers for fewer collisions).  Anyway, when the load factor is kept within such a range - say ~0.5 to 1.0 - you're very unlikely to have more than a couple elements at the bucket you'll search for the key that's not actually in the table.

Aside from separate chaining, there is another way of storing data in hash tables called closed hashing or open addressing, where - if there's been a collision - you use other buckets.  There are many ways to choose those buckets: linear probing means you look at successive buckets, quadratic probing means you try e.g. +1, +4, +9, +16 from the hashed-to bucket.  With these approaches, as the load factor approaches 1.0, or if the hash function is poor quality, you're more likely to approach worst-case performance of O(N), but there's no point using such a hash table if you're not going to prevent that and have a lower load factor or better hash function - which will keep performance at the O(1) amortised level.